# How I can create image that is >2M from phpmy admin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to copy a database in phph I must create a file.sql that is > 2MB but the maxium size is 2 MB. How I can create an image in phpmyadmin that hasn't respect this maxium size?

Comment: What do you mean by "image"? If you are talking about creating an export file, you could export the DB in parts, for example, export half the tables to one file, and the other half to a second file.

Comment: @Sloan Thrarahser yes I know But If the size of the file that I have export before is > 2MB , I can't upload after this file, How can I resolve this?

Comment: Split the file. You should be able to edit the file, and find a place where you can move part of it to another file.

Comment: Change the parameter in **php.ini** file to increase the file size that is permitted.